# React Native appending Text component inside of another Text Component

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

I have a text component

```
<Text ref="text" style{...}>{this.state.te}</Text>
```

and I would like to insert and append other `<Text></Text>`

so when the event fires on a button I want it to insert a new `<Text></Text>` to look like this

```
<Text ref="text" style{...}>
   <Text ref="text" style{...}>first</Text>
   <Text ref="text" style{...}>second</Text>
   <Text ref="text" style{...}>third</Text>
</Text>
```

this is what my event looks like

```
insertText(){
 this.setState({te: this.state.te + <Text style={...}>{this.refs.newText.props.value}</Text>})
```

}

when I do this all it renders is `"[object object]"` inside of the Text Component

if I use

```
 this.setState({te: <Text style={...}>{this.refs.newText.props.value}</Text>})
```

it will render the text just fine with a single `<Text></Text>` element.

any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Edit:

this.state.te holds `te: <Text></Text>`

Comment: Can you show what this.state.te holds? Thanks.

Comment: I have edited my post. thanks

Comment: I have also tried this.refs.text.pops.children.__proto__.push(<Text>new node</Text>); but that does not add any children. same result adds "[object object]... + [object object]" to the first element inside of the array

Comment: @AKADER What can be done, if i want to append TextInput instead of Text ?

Comment: @SatanPandeya Have you tried the accepted answers code with `TextInput` instead? My guess is the same thing would happen. I can't actually try it out my new mac isn't set up yet I just bought it.

Comment: @AKADER Yeah, I tried that . The `TextInput` is not pushed. Can you help me like if I want to push something like: `TextInput | Text` and so on using two separate button ?

Comment: @SatanPandeya Sure, Can you post your code in a seperate question and link to it in a comment so I can take a look at what you have? Thanks.

Comment: Here is the a question where i can only push `TextInput | TextInput` and so on. I want like `TextInput | Text | TextInput` and so on. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39571931/append-textinput-component-one-after-another-when-press-button-in-react-native

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, check out what I have below. I've essentially created an array of text values that are place in between two `<Text>` fields, and when the insertText function is called, it pushes a new text element to the array, then resets the state of the array to the `te` property:

```
  getInitialState: function() {
        return {
         te: [<Text>Yo</Text>],
         index:1
        }
  },

  insertText: function() {
    this.state.te.push(
        <Text>Text number {this.state.index}</Text>
    )
    this.setState({
        index: this.state.index + 1,
        te: this.state.te
    })
  },

  render: function() {

    var MyText = function(t) {
      return(
        <Text>
          {t}
        </Text>
      )           
    }

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
            {MyText(this.state.te)}
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={ () => this.insertText() } style={{ marginTop:20, height:60, flexDirection: 'row', backgroundColor: '#ededed', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 22 }}>Add Text</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    );
```

I've set up the full working project [here](https://rnplay.org/apps/Itk6RQ). Full code is also posted below.

https://rnplay.org/apps/Itk6RQ

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');
var {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TouchableHighlight
} = React;

var SampleApp = React.createClass({

  getInitialState: function() {
        return {
       te: [<Text>Yo</Text>],
         index:1
    }
  },

  insertText: function() {
    this.state.te.push(
        <Text>Text number {this.state.index}</Text>
    )
    this.setState({
        index: this.state.index + 1,
      te: this.state.te
    })
  },

  render: function() {

    var MyText = function(t) {
      return(
        <Text>
          {t}
        </Text>
      )           
    }

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
            {MyText(this.state.te)}
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={ () => this.insertText() } style={{ marginTop:20, height:60, flexDirection: 'row', backgroundColor: '#ededed', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 22 }}>Add Text</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    );
  }
});

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    marginTop: 60
  }
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('SampleApp', () => SampleApp);
```

Comment: Wow thanks, I didn't think the solution would be so simple. Excellent job.