# Append TextInput component one after another when press button in React Native

Tags: android, react-native

I am new in `React Native`.

I am using two button to add `TextInput` component in the view.
When I press `Add` button, it pushes one `TextInput` component into the view and when I press `Add Again` button, it pushes another `TextInput` component below previous one.

But when I press `Add` button again, it pushes the `TextInput` component below the first one. But I want to push it below the last one.

Like : `Add |Add | Add again.`

But I need `Add | Add Again | Add` and so on.

What can be done to achieve this ?
I have followed [this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjXsYzmqJvPAhVC3GMKHT8eBjkQFgghMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F35524026%2Freact-native-dynamically-add-element-to-dom-on-button-press&usg=AFQjCNEwa8nzc2b7cq4Apkjr4Szy9QY7kg&sig2=YijPjx_aD5i01O2R3aOQdw).

```
'use strict';

import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TouchableHighlight,
  TextInput,
 } from 'react-native';

let index = 0 

class Test extends Component{
constructor(){
super();
this.state = {
  arr: []
};
}
insertSomeThing(){
this.state.arr.push(index++)
this.setState({ arr: this.state.arr })
}

render() {
let arr = this.state.arr.map((r, i) => {
    return (
      <View key={ i } style={styles.insertStyle}>
        <TextInput placeholder = 'abc' />
      </View>
      );
})
let arrAnother = this.state.arr.map((r, i) => {
    return (
      <View key={ i } style={styles.insertStyle}>
        <TextInput placeholder = 'def' />
      </View>
      );
})

return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
  <View>
    <TouchableHighlight 
      onPress={ this.insertSomeThing.bind(this) } 
      style={styles.button}>
        <Text>Add</Text>
    </TouchableHighlight>
  </View>
  <View>
    <TouchableHighlight 
      onPress={ this.insertSomeThing.bind(this) } 
      style={styles.button}>
        <Text>Add Again</Text>
    </TouchableHighlight>
  </View>
  { arr }
  {arrAnother}
  </View>
);
}
}

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
flex: 1,
marginTop: 60,
  }, 
  insertStyle: {
height:40,
alignItems: 'center',
justifyContent: 'center',
borderBottomColor: '#ededed',
borderBottomWidth: 1
  },
  button: {
alignItems: 'center',
justifyContent: 'center',
height:55,
backgroundColor: '#ededed',
marginBottom:10
  }
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('Test', () => Test);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling `insertSomeThing` function and this function push a new `<Text>` in variable `arr` and then it is rendered in the following order:

```
</View>
    { arr }
    {arrAnother}
</View>
```

If you want to insert a different TextView at the end of the list you must remove `{arrAnother}` and modify your map functions. Your code will look like this:

```
insertSomeThing( placeholder ){
  this.state.arr.push({index:index++, placeholder:placeholder});
  this.setState({ arr: this.state.arr });
}

render() {
  let arr = this.state.arr.map((r, i) => {
    return (
      <View key={ i } style={styles.insertStyle}>
        <TextInput placeholder = {r.placeholder} />
      </View>
    );
  });

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View>
        <TouchableHighlight 
          onPress={ () => this.insertSomeThing('add') } 
          style={styles.button}>

          <Text>Add</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
      <View>
        <TouchableHighlight 
          onPress={ () => this.insertSomeThing('addAgain') } 
          style={styles.button}>
             <Text>Add Again</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
      { arr }
    </View>
  );
}
```

**EDIT**

To handle `onChangeText` your TextInput will look like this:

```
let arr = this.state.arr.map((r, i) => {

    var ref = 'textinput'+i;

    return (
      <View key={ i } style={styles.insertStyle}>
        <TextInput ref={ref} onChangeText={(text) => this._onChangeText(text,ref)} />
      </View>
    );
  });
```

You have to define `_onChangeText` in your component to handle the event. You will receive text and reference to the input. You later can reference the input using `this.refs[ref]`.

Comment: How to use onChangeText and value , so that i can retrieve the the input text seperately ?

Comment: Final one, What do I need to change in mapping function or some where if I want to push Component like :  TextInput | Text | TextInput  and so on ?

Comment: You have to push more info in your `this.state.arr`. You can add a type parameter to know which type of component is. Example: `this.state.arr.push({index:index++, placeholder:placeholder, type:'textInput'});`, and then in your `map` function you have to determine what to return for each type in `arr`.