# React Native ref not called on dynamic component

Tags: react-native

I have a component that dynamically renders different components based off of `props`. I am unable to set the `ref` on one of them. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39760559/react-native-ref-not-working-in-dynamic-adding-rows) had a duplicate `ref`, which I do not have. In addition, the components are built inside the `render` function.

Here is my code:

```
render() {
  let content = null
  switch(this.props.type) {
    case 'follow'
      content = <View ref={comp => this._followBtn = comp} />
      break
    // ...etc
  }
  return (
    <View ref={comp => (this._wrapper = comp)>
      { content }
    </View>
  )
}
```

I need access to `_followBtn` from a parent component rendering the `_wrapper`.
I have only accomplished accessing `_wrapper`.

Does my problem stem from the fact that these are dynamically generated?
The `ref` prop never seems to be called.

Comment: Are you actually returning the JSX?

Comment: @AndrewLi Yes, it renders my Components as expected.

Comment: Tried it myself, it works fine! I am able to access the child components ref as well. Do one thing console 'this' of the element and check '_followBtn' you should be able to find it.

Comment: @MinkeshJain Thanks but I still don't see it... I've been pretty much `console.log`ing every component in the tree. Seems like when I `console.log` the return of the `ref` it's never called, so nothing is being assigned to `this._followBtn`.